# Javascript If-Else Statement in For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use JavaScript and the Google Maps API to plot a number of markers on a map; I have a large array of objects containing key-value pairs as follows:

```
xyz: [ { name: 'abc', loc: { lat: 0.000000, lng: 0.000000 } }, ... , ... ]
```

I have a For-Loop that iterates through this array and plots a marker at xyz.loc for each object in the array (see below). Now, I'm trying to change the icon used for each marker based on the xyz.name property.

I've defined two different custom marker icons and their associated shape (*xyzMarkerIcon1*, *xyzMarkerIcon2* and *xyzMarkerShape*) and I'm trying to switch which one is used using an If-Else statement as follows:

```
var xyzMarkerIcon = {};
for (i in xyz) {

  if (xyz[i].name = 'abc') {
    xyzMarkerIcon = xyzMarkerIcon1
  }
  else {
    xyzMarkerIcon = xyzMarkerIcon2
  }

  xyzMarkerArray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: xyz[i].loc,
    icon: xyzMarkerIcon,
    shape: xyzMarkerShape,
  });
}
```

The For-loop works fine, but the If-Else statement seems to be overlooked after the first iteration; all of the objects in the array are plotted successfully but all using the first instance of *xyzMarkerIcon*.

I feel like this should be a simple enough problem, but I just can't figure it out! Thanks for your help!

Comment: that is because you are having xyz[0].name as abc and then other? that is why it is being overlooked ( rather not overlooked at all ? )

Comment: `xyz[i].name = 'abc'` this is assignment not comparison, replace `=` with `==`. `if (string)` is always true so always the first icon is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the == 'abc'

```
var xyzMarkerIcon = {};
for (i in xyz) {

  if (xyz[i].name == 'abc') {
    xyzMarkerIcon = xyzMarkerIcon1
  }
  else {
    xyzMarkerIcon = xyzMarkerIcon2
  }

  xyzMarkerArray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: xyz[i].loc,
    icon: xyzMarkerIcon,
    shape: xyzMarkerShape,
  });
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yes! I thought it would be something simple that I had missed! Many thanks.